# Why does Python's __import__ require fromlist?

Tags: python, python-import

In Python, if you want to programmatically import a module, you can do:

```
module = __import__('module_name')
```

If you want to import a submodule, you would think it would be a simple matter of:

```
module = __import__('module_name.submodule')
```

Of course, this doesn't work; you just get `module_name` again. You have to do:

```
module = __import__('module_name.submodule', fromlist=['blah'])
```

**Why?** The actual value of `fromlist` don't seem to matter at all, as long as it's non-empty. What is the point of requiring an argument, then ignoring its values?

Most stuff in Python seems to be done for good reason, but for the life of me, I can't come up with any reasonable explanation for this behavior to exist.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

In fact, the behaviour of `__import__()` is entirely because of the implementation of the `import` statement, which calls `__import__()`. There's basically five slightly different ways `__import__()` can be called by `import` (with two main categories):

```
import pkg
import pkg.mod
from pkg import mod, mod2
from pkg.mod import func, func2
from pkg.mod import submod
```

In the first *and* the second case, the `import` statement should assign the "left-most" module object to the "left-most" name: `pkg`. After `import pkg.mod` you can do `pkg.mod.func()` because the `import` statement introduced the local name `pkg`, which is a module object that has a `mod` attribute. So, the `__import__()` function has to return the "left-most" module object so it can be assigned to `pkg`. Those two import statements thus translate into:

```
pkg = __import__('pkg')
pkg = __import__('pkg.mod')
```

In the third, fourth and fifth case, the `import` statement has to do more work: it has to assign to (potentially) multiple names, which it has to get from the module object. The `__import__()` function can only return one object, and there's no real reason to make it retrieve each of those names from the module object (and it would make the implementation a lot more complicated.) So the simple approach would be something like (for the third case):

```
tmp = __import__('pkg')
mod = tmp.mod
mod2 = tmp.mod2
```

However, that won't work if `pkg` is a package and `mod` or `mod2` are modules in that package *that are not already imported*, as they are in the third and fifth case. The `__import__()` function needs to know that `mod` and `mod2` are names that the `import` statement will want to have accessible, so that it can see if they are modules and try to import them too. So the call is closer to:

```
tmp = __import__('pkg', fromlist=['mod', 'mod2'])
mod = tmp.mod
mod2 = tmp.mod2
```

which causes `__import__()` to try and load `pkg.mod` and `pkg.mod2` as well as `pkg` (but if `mod` or `mod2` don't exist, it's not an error in the `__import__()` call; producing an error is left to the `import` statement.) But that still isn't the right thing for the fourth and fifth example, because if the call were so:

```
tmp = __import__('pkg.mod', fromlist=['submod'])
submod = tmp.submod
```

then `tmp` would end up being `pkg`, as before, and not the `pkg.mod` module you want to get the `submod` attribute from. The implementation could have decided to make it so the `import` statement does extra work, splitting the package name on `.` like the `__import__()` function already does and traversing the names, but this would have meant duplicating some of the effort. So, instead, the implementation made `__import__()` return the *right-most* module instead of the *left-most* one **if and only if** fromlist is passed and not empty.

(The `import pkg as p` and `from pkg import mod as m` syntax doesn't change anything about this story except which local names get assigned to -- the `__import__()` function sees nothing different when `as` is used, it all remains in the `import` statement implementation.)

Answer (score 7):

I still feel weird when I read the answer, so I tried the below code samples.

First, try to build below file structure:

```
tmpdir
  |A
     |__init__.py
     | B.py
     | C.py
```

Now A is a `package`, and `B` or `C` is a `module`.  So when we try some code like these in ipython:

Second, run the sample code in ipython:

```
  In [2]: kk = __import__('A',fromlist=['B'])

  In [3]: dir(kk)
  Out[3]: 
  ['B',
   '__builtins__',
   '__doc__',
   '__file__',
   '__name__',
   '__package__',
   '__path__']
```

It seems like the fromlist works as we expected. But things become wired when we try to do the same things on a `module`. Suppose we have a module called C.py and code in it:

```
  handlers = {}

  def hello():
      print "hello"

  test_list = []
```

So now we try to do the same thing on it.

```
  In [1]: ls
  C.py

  In [2]: kk = __import__('C')

  In [3]: dir(kk)
  Out[3]: 
  ['__builtins__',
   '__doc__',
   '__file__',
   '__name__',
   '__package__',
   'handlers',
   'hello',
   'test_list']
```

So when we just want to import the test_list, does it work?

```
  In [1]: kk = __import__('C',fromlist=['test_list'])

  In [2]: dir(kk)
  Out[2]: 
  ['__builtins__',
   '__doc__',
   '__file__',
   '__name__',
   '__package__',
   'handlers',
   'hello',
   'test_list']
```

As the result shows, when we try to use fromlist on a `module` rather than a `package`, the fromlist param doesn't help at all because `module` has been compiled. Once it is imported, there is no way to ignore the other ones.

Answer (score 4):

The answer can found found in the documentation for `__import__`:

> The fromlist should be a list of names to emulate `from name import ...`, or an empty list to emulate `import name`.
>
> When importing a module from a package, note that `__import__('A.B', ...)` returns package A when fromlist is empty, but its submodule B when fromlist is not empty.

So basically, that's just how the implementation of `__import__` works: if you want the submodule, you pass a `fromlist` containing something you want to import from the submodule, and the implementation if `__import__` is such that the submodule is returned.

**Further explanation**

I think the semantics exist so that the most relevant module is returned. In other words, say I have a package `foo` containing module `bar` with function `baz`. If I:

```
import foo.bar
```

Then I refer to `baz` as

```
foo.bar.baz()
```

This is like `__import__("foo.bar", fromlist=[])`.

If instead I import with:

```
from foo import bar
```

Then I refer to `baz` as
    bar.baz()

Which would be similar to `__imoort__("foo.bar", fromlist=["something"])`.

If I do:

```
from foo.bar import baz
```

Then I refer to `baz` as

```
baz()
```

Which is like `__import__("foo.bar", fromlist=["baz"])`.

So in the first case, I'd have to use the fully-qualified name, hence `__import__` returns the first module name you'd use to refer to the imported elements, that being `foo`. In the last case, `bar` is the most specific module containing the imported elements, so it makes sense that `__import__` would return the `foo.bar` module.

The second case is a little weird, but I am guessing it was written that way to support importing a module using the `from <package> import <module>` syntax, and in that case `bar` is still the most specific module to return.

Comment: Saying "that's just how the implementation works" doesn't answer my question. Why does it work that way?

Saying "to emulate the from name import …" form is closer, but under what circumstances would you need that? The fromlist doesn't make a whit of difference to how __import__ actually works, so I don't see where there's a case where you'd need to pass it to emulate anything, except what should be the obvious behavior of the function.

Comment: You're right, it is begging the question. I updated my answer to give a more relevant reply.