# python __import__ all files in folder not working

Tags: python, import, module, directory

```
from os import listdir
modo= [name.split(".py")[0] for name in listdir("scripts") if name.endswith(".py")]
modules = {}
for modu in modo:
    modules[modu] = __import__(modu)
test_samp.function("test")
```

Hello!
If, say "test_samp.py" exists in the scripts directory, why does
this not allow me to run test_samp.function("test")?
It returns:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function function at 0x8e39204>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_this.py", line 6, in function
    test_samp.function("test")  
NameError: global name 'test_samp' is not defined
```

Comment: do you have an ``__init__.py`` file?

Comment: Yeah, but whether it's there or it's not, there's no difference. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are not defining `test_samp` you are defining `modules['test_samp']`. Plus if it's in scripts you need to import `scripts.test_samp`

in yor case use a package.Add an empty (or not) `__init__.py` (with 2 underscores). and use `import scripts`. Access your function with `scripts.test_samp.function("test")`. And you could use `reload(scripts)` to reload all of the package.

Comment: Unless scripts is in your python path.

Comment: Thank you, but then why does:
    for modu in modo:
        __import__(modu)
Also not work?

Comment: @Lattyware yes. but still a better a way is to use a package with an __init__.py file

Comment: what do you mean does not work ? the error you posted has nothing to do with that statement

Comment: How would I perform this?
It is important that I would be able to use the reload(all_modules_in_folder) function.
What would __init__.py need to contain in order for it to work?

Comment: That's the error displayed in the terminal window when I ran that script using the interpreter on XBN Linux, python 2.5/2.7

Comment: @jadkik94 Of course, I was just making note of another possibility, not saying it was a better way.

Comment: It is indeed, thank you :) For some reason however, I cannot pull any functions from the modules located in that folder:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'function'

Comment: Try `import scripts.test_samp`. Read more about packages and modules in the python docs" It's more detailed.

Comment: @jadkik94 aah, thank you! Checking out http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html 6.4 now. Thanks heaps for your's and everyone else's help! :)

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems in your code:

- `__import__` doesn't import into global namespace, it **returns** a module
- you're trying to import `test_samp` while it's `scripts.test_samp`

What you actually want is:

```
scripts = __import__("scripts", fromlist=modo)
scripts.test_samp.function("test")
```

Above `__import__` returns `scripts` package with all the sub-modules loaded. Don't forget to make `scripts` directory a package by creating `__init__.py` in it.

See also: [Why does Python's __import__ require fromlist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724260/why-does-pythons-import-require-fromlist)

Comment: Thank you for your help! That seems to have gotten it working, however __init__.py has peaked my interest. I am having issues with it though, as referenced in a comment in the above post.

Answer (score 1):

You can run it using this:

```
modules["test_samp"].function("test")
```