# __import__ and name is not found error in python

Tags: python, import

When a.py has this code:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        print 'hi'
```

I use class A with this code:

```
import a
b = a.A()
```

I need to do the same thing with `__import__`, and I tried this page:[Why does Python's __import__ require fromlist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724260/why-does-pythons-import-require-fromlist)

```
__import__("a", fromlist=[])
#import a
b = a.A()
```

However, I got `name 'a' is not defined` error. What might be wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`__import__`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__) returns a module.  You need to bind the result to a name:

```
a = __import__("a")
a.A()
```