# Importing a module at runtime

Tags: python, python-import

I'm trying to import a module using `__import__()`. I need to use `__import__` becuase I don't know which module I'll need before runtime.

Let's say the module I'll need is `MyClass`. The file tree is `api/apps/myapp/my_class.py`, and the class i have in `my_class.py` is `MyClass`. Now, to access the methods of `MyClass` what I'm doing is this:

```
my_class_module =  __import__('api.apps.myapp.my_class')
my_class= my_class_module.MyClass()
```

But I'm getting this error:
`'module' object has no attribute 'MyClass'`

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724260/why-does-pythons-import-require-fromlist

Comment: It seems to be a duplicate, however here the question is practical: "how do I" when in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724260/why-does-pythons-import-require-fromlist it is a "how does it works" question. Same for the answers.

Comment: In case the *possible duplicate* is not asserted, I'll add a link to this details explanation in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `__import__` return a reference to the **first** module. In your example, it is `api`. The solution is to use the `fromlist` parameter:

```
my_class_module =  __import__('api.apps.myapp.my_class', fromlist=[''])
```

From the `__import__` documentation:

[...]
When importing a module from a package, note that **___import___('A.B', ...)
returns package A when fromlist is empty, but its submodule B when
fromlist is not empty**.  [...]

For details on the reason it does so, see [Why does Python's __import__ require fromlist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724260/why-does-pythons-import-require-fromlist)