# how to import or call a python module/class in other modules with different file paths

Tags: python-2.7, exception

I want to follow this structure for a WEB "WSGI pep 3333" API (educational purposes):

```
/home/
 `--app.py
 `--API_module/
    `--__init__.py
    `--api.py
    `--exceptions.py
 `--modules/
     `--default/
        `--__init__.py
         `--default.py
```

`app.py` calls `API_module` with something like:

```
app = API_module.api()
```

the `api.py` based on "HTTP GET requests" will load modules stored on directory named `modules`, for now, I am just loading a module named `default`.

`api.py` looks like:

```
import os
import imp
from exceptions import HTTPError, HTTPException

class API(object):
    def __call__(self, env, start_response):
        self.env = env
        self.method = env['REQUEST_METHOD']
        try:
            body = self.router()
            body.dispatch()
        except HTTPError, e:
             print 'HTTP method not valid %s' % e
        except, Exception e:
             print 'something went wrong'

        start_response(status, headers)
        yield body

     def router():
         module_path = '/home/modules/default/default.py'
         if not os.access(module_path, os.R_OK):
             raise HTTPException()
         else:
             py_mod = imp.load_source('default', '/home/modules/default/default.py'
             return py_mod.Resource(self)
```

and `default.py` contains something like:

```
class Resoure(object):
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app

    def dispatch(self):
       raise HTTPException()
```

So far I can import dynamically the modules but if I want to raise an exception from the `default.py` module I get an:

> global name 'HTTPException' is not defined

Therefore I would like to know, how to take advantage of the `API_module/exceptions` and use them in all the dynamically modules.

Any ideas, suggestions comments are welcome.

Comment: @Paolo, what about if the modules are in: `modules/API/v0/default/default.py` the emtpy `__init__.py` would be inside each subdir like modules/, APO/, v0 and default ?

Comment: Yes, that is a way to do it. Or you can play with `sys.path` for example by adding `modules/API/v0` to the list. But then you can't use `from modules.default ...` syntax which is very elegant to me. You'll instead end up using `from default import default` which is unclear from a code reader perspective.

Comment: I notice that I had to use `__import__('root.api.v0.default.default', fromlist=[''])` the fromlist made the trick. it is ok ?

Comment: You're right @nbari! I forgot about it. For more informations about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724260/why-does-pythons-import-require-fromlist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a matter of `sys.path`.

In your setup, since your `API_module` is included from `app.py` you should have the root of your application in your `sys.path` so you should just include the `API_module` in the usual way:

```
from API_module import exceptions
```

or

```
from API_module.exceptions import *
```

based on how you use it.

Btw, i suggest you use `pymod = __import__('modules.default.default', fromlist=[''])` and put an `__init__.py' file in the`modules/` root directory.