# How to dynamically import module class

Tags: python, import, module

I have following structure:

```
app.py

modules
    |
    -- __init__.py
    |
    -- update.py
```

I try to call function from `modules/update.py` dynamicaly:

```
import sys

arguments = sys.argv
module = arguments[1]
command = arguments[2]
moduleObj = __import__('modules.'+module)            # returns module object "modules"
submodule = getattr(moduleObj, module)    # returns the module object "modules.update"
moduleClass = getattr(submodule, module)  # returns the class object "update"
    # this works because the class has the same name as the file it contains it.
    # if the names are different then you have to change that accordingly 
result = getattr(moduleClass, command) # returns the attribute with the name =command
print result()
```

but I catch a error:

> File "app.py", line 12, in 
>       print result() TypeError: unbound method test() must be called with update instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

What's wrong? Help me please!

ps: `update.py` code:

```
import os

class update:
    def repositories(self):
        os.system('sudo apt-get update')

    def system(self):
        os.system('sudo apt-get -y upgrade')

    def distributive(self):
        os.system('sudo apt-get -y dist-upgrade')

    def all(self):
        self.repositories()
        self.system()
        self.distributive()

    def test(self):
        print 'test complete!'
```

Comment: you mean `__init__.py`

Comment: you don't need semicolon `;` at the end of each statement in python. Please make your structure clearer, what is the name of the package that contains `update.py`?

Comment: I removed semicolon, but not a problem. There is no package, I have only empty __init __.py and update.py file in modules folder

Comment: If you put print statements after each line, such as `print(moduleObj)`, you'll get a much better idea where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are passing the arguments like this:

```
python app.py update attribute
```

so your program interprets it like this:

```
getattr(__import__('modules.update.update'),command)()
```

as you don't have a module with that name you get that import error.

If I understood correctly you have the following files structure:

```
app.py

modules
    |
    -- __init__.py
    |
    -- update.py
```

**Edit:**
let me suppose for the sake of explaining, that your `update.py` contains:

```
class update(object):
    name = 'update_name'
```

now in your `app.py`:

```
import sys

arguments = sys.argv
module = arguments[1]
command = arguments[2]
moduleObj = __import__(module)            # returns module object "modules"
submodule = getattr(moduleObj, module)    # returns the module object "modules.update"
moduleClass = getattr(submodule, module)  # returns the class object "update"
    # this works because the class has the same name as the file it contains it.
    # if the names are different then you have to change that accordingly 
name_attr = getattr(moduleClass, command) # returns the attribute with the name =command
```

to see what you got add some prints:

```
print moduleObj 
print submodule 
print moduleClass
print name_attr
```

you can call your script now with:

```
python app.py update name
```

and the output will look like:

```
<module 'modules' from '<path>/modules/__init__.pyc'>
<module 'modules.update' from '<path>/modules/update.pyc'>
<class 'modules.update.update'>
update_name
```

I think now you can manipulate the code however you want to get any object you like, or even pass them as arguments like `update` and `name` earlier.

**Edit:**

you can not call unbounded method, you need to create an instance of that class and then call the method for that instance, that's what the error is saying.
so you need to do something like in the following example:

```
import sys

arguments = sys.argv
module = arguments[1]
command = arguments[2]
moduleObj = __import__(module)            # returns module "modules"
submodule = getattr(moduleObj, module)    # returns the module "modules.update"
localInstance = submodule.update()           # create instance of class 'update'
localInstance.test()                         # call instance method
```

and this will print:

```
test complete!
```

**PS:**

*It is not encouraged to use some words for your method names or variables like `system` or `all`, better change them.*

hope this helps.

Comment: No, I need to call class "update" from modules/update.py. Please, see the first post, I updated code

Comment: it doesn't work fully - please, see the first post, I updated the code

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the updated question:

The error in your updated code is due to the fact that you need to make an instance of the class before calling its method:

```
result = getattr(moduleClass(), command)
```

(Note the parentheses).

---

I think the error originates here:

```
moduleObj = __import__('modules.'+module)
```

When you call [`__import__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__) without the `fromlist` parameter, it returns the *left-mode* module, not the *right-most* module. To be clearer, let me give an example:

```
In [3]: __import__('xml.dom')
Out[3]: <module 'xml' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/__init__.pyc'>
```

Notice the `xml` module is returned, *not* the `xml.dom` module!
Even though `xml.dom` is not returned, it has been imported. You can access `xml.dom` through the `sys.modules` dict:

```
In [11]: sys.modules['xml.dom']
Out[11]: <module 'xml.dom' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/__init__.pyc'>
```

To get `__import__` to return the `xml.dom` module, you need to use the `fromlist` parameter:

```
In [4]: __import__('xml.dom', fromlist=[''])
Out[4]: <module 'xml.dom' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/__init__.pyc'>
```

More information on why `__import__` behaves this way [can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2725668/190597).

So here are 3 different ways to fix your code:

- Use `fromlist`:

  ```
  moduleObj = __import__('modules.'+module, fromlist=[''])
  ```

  (It doesn't matter what you assign to `fromlist`, it just has to be a
  non-empty list of strings.)
- Use `sys.modules`:

  ```
  name = 'modules.'+module
  __import__(name)
  moduleObj = sys.modules[name]
  ```
- Alternatively, use [importlib.import_module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html#module-importlib):

  ```
  import importlib
  moduleObj = importlib.import_module('modules.'+module)
  ```

Of these three, I think the third is the most readable.