# Package python codes which uses __import__ function

Tags: python, python-2.7

My directory structure is:

```
./
├── foo
│   ├── bar.py
│   ├── foo.py
│   └── __init__.py
└── main.py
```

with:

bar.py:

```
def get_data():
    return 'ha'
```

foo.py:

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.lib = __import__('bar', fromlist=['bar'])
        self.data = self.lib.get_data()

    def print_data(self):
        print(self.data)

if __name__=='__main__':
    f = foo()
    f.print_data()
```

`__init__`.py:

```
from foo import foo
```

and main.py:

```
from foo import foo

a = foo()
a.print_data()
```

Running `python foo.py` I get `ha` correctly, but running `python main.py` I get the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    a = foo()
  File ".../foo/foo.py", line 3, in __init__
    self.lib = __import__('bar')
ImportError: No module named bar
```

My requirements are 1) making `foo` to work like a package, 2) using `__import__` in `foo.py`'s `__init__` function instead of `import` in the first line of `foo.py`.

I changed line 3 of `foo.py` to `self.lib = __import__('foo.bar', fromlist=['bar'])`, and then got the correct answer. But that is not I want, since running `python foo.py` will lead to a failure and that is not a package solution when the whole directory `./` become another package. It seems an import path problem that I cannot figure out.

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Changing `foo.py` to that makes it work correctly:

```
import importlib


class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.lib = importlib.import_module('foo.bar')
        self.data = self.lib.get_data()

    def print_data(self):
        print(self.data)

if __name__=='__main__':
    f = foo()
    f.print_data()
```

Comment: Thanks. But it is like the solution in my last paragrah in the question. It works right only for `python main.py`.

Comment: @Taz'dingo Oh, sorry, I see. I think you cant avoid the error, because imports in python are not relative to directory structure, they relative to `__main__` module.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724260/why-does-pythons-import-require-fromlist) makes me think that `import bar`(common import way in first line of the `.py` script) is implemented by `__import__()`, and `import bar` with `self.data = bar.get_data()` can solve the problem. That's why I think my requirements have a solution.