# Given a path to a Python source file, how do I find which package the file belongs to?

Tags: python, package, python-importlib

Given a path to a file, I need the package name to pass to `importlib.import_module()` so that relative imports will work correctly.  I can't import it and then check `module.__package__` because it won't import successfully.

Comment: Can you add what you have tried to far including your folder / file structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one rather generic method:

```
import pathlib
import sys


def get_module_name(path):
    f = pathlib.Path(path).resolve()
    for i in map(pathlib.Path, sys.path):
        try:
            f.relative_to(i)
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            *parts, fname = f.relative_to(i).parts
            return ".".join(parts), [f.stem]

module, fromlist = get_module_name("Programming/Python/kernprof.py")

print(module, fromlist)

imported_module = __import__(module, fromlist=fromlist)

print(imported_module)
print(getattr(imported_module, fromlist[0]))
```

Outputs:

```
Programming.Python ['kernprof']
<module 'Programming.Python' (namespace)>
<module 'Programming.Python.kernprof' from '/home/matthew/Programming/Python/kernprof.py'>
```

This solution can handle import with any path from `sys.path`, but cannot do relative imports (imports above the `sys.path`). For the how `__import__` is used, see [Why does Python's __import__ require fromlist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724260/why-does-pythons-import-require-fromlist).

Comment: This method has some limitations because it makes a static determination using the directory structure without processing __init__.py files or other ways to monkey with deciding which files belong to which package, but it's good enough for my purposes.

Comment: Yeah, processing `__init__`s and co would be pretty complicated, with some possibly unwanted results.

Answer (score 0):

What about this helper ?

```
import os


def get_parent_package(path):
    parent_path = os.path.split(path)[0]
    while parent_path != os.sep:
        if '__init__.py' in os.listdir(parent_path):
            return os.path.basename(parent_path)
        parent_path = os.path.split(parent_path)[0]
    return None
```

parent_path != os.sep must be improved if you are under windows.

Comment: The major problem with this, as I discovered, is that in Python 3.3+  __init__.py is no longer needed to define a module, see Nick Coghlan's discussion at http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html.  There can be other problems with traversing the directory tree from the bottom up for packages containing subpackages.