# Import arbitrary subdirectory modules

Tags: python, import

Present situation:

- I have a script: `program.py`.
- I have a directory: `/imports`. Which contains an arbitrary amount of modules in subdirectories.
- Python's package directory syntax is being used.

  ```
   __init__.py
   program.py
   /imports
       __init__.py
       /module a
           __init__.py
           other_files.py
       /module b
           __init__.py
           other
  ```

Intention:

- `program.py` should import every subdirectory in `/imports`.
- `program.py` needs object access to the modules. For example, `imports['name'].Service()`.

Remark: I don't feel like illustrating my purpose or questioning the design choice. I'm using the above workaround.  
The problem is described below.

**The existing code:**

```
import os

modules = []
IMPORT_PATH = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'imports')
to_import = [name for name in os.listdir(IMPORT_PATH) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(IMPORT_PATH, name))]
modules = [__import__('imports.' + x) for x in to_import]
print modules
```

**Output:**

```
[<module 'imports' from '/code/test/imports/__init__.pyc'>, <module 'imports' from '/code/test/imports/__init__.pyc'>]
```

**Desired output:**

```
[<module 'B' from '/code/test/imports/B'>, <module 'C' from '/code/test/imports/C'>]
```

Comment: Use [`__import__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#__import__)

Comment: import x wouldn't work because import doesnt take a variable. Try `__import__` or using `importlib.import_module`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem identified: The `fromlist=[]` argument for `__import__()` is missing. See [Why does Python's __import__ require fromlist?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2724260/2825347) for elaboration.

**Corrected example:**

```
modules = {}
IMPORT_PATH = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'imports')
to_import = [name for name in os.listdir(IMPORT_PATH) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(IMPORT_PATH, name))]
for x in to_import:
    modules[x] = __import__('imports.' + x, fromlist=['*'])
```

**Output:**

```
{'C': <module 'imports.C' from '/code/test/imports/C/__init__.pyc'>, 
'B': <module 'imports.B' from '/code/test/imports/B/__init__.pyc'>}
```

**Achieved result:**

- Now `modules[dir_name].Service()` can be used in `program.py`.