# How do I reload a python submodule?

Tags: python

I'm loading a submodule in python (2.7.10) with `from app import sub` where `sub` has a `config` variable. So I can run `print sub.config` and see a bunch of config variables. Not super complex.

If I change the config variables in the script, there must be a way to reload the module and see the change. I found a few instructions that indicated that `reload(app.sub)` would work, but I get an error:

```
NameError: name 'app' is not defined
```

And if I do just `reload(sub)` the error is:

```
TypeError: reload() argument must be module
```

If I do `import app` I can view the config with `print app.sub.config` and reload with `reload(app)`

-- if I do `import app` and then run

I found instructions to automate reloading:
[Reloading submodules in IPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364050/reloading-submodules-in-ipython)

but is there no way to reload a submodule manually?

Comment: What version of Python?

Comment: @KarenClark: It must be Python2, because `reload()` isn't around in Python3.

Comment: (edited to answer your Qs.)

Answer (score 10):

With python3,I try this:

```
import importlib
import sys

def m_reload():
    for k,v in sys.modules.items():
        if k.startswith('your-package-name'):
            importlib.reload(v)
```

Comment: This caused `RuntimeError: dictionary keys changed during iteration` on my end. So I iterate over a copy of the dict items `for k,v in list(sys.modules.items()):`

Answer (score 0):

When you `from foo import bar`, you now have a module object named `bar` in your namespace, so you can

```
from foo import bar

bar.do_the_thing()  # or whatever

reload(bar)
```

If you want some more details on how different import forms work, I personally found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2725668/939586) particularly helpful, myself.

Comment: That approach always gives me an error: "TypeError: reload() argument must be module"

Answer (score 0):

```
from importlib import reload
import sys
ls=[]
#making copy to avoid regeneration of sys.modules
for i,j in sys.modules.items():
    r,v=i,j
    ls.append((r,v))

for i in ls:
    if i[0] == 'my_library_name':
        reload(i[1])
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

@6c1 answer did not work for me.

Here is a modification of it that did work for me.

```
from foo import bar
bar.do_the_thing()

del bar
import sys
import importlib
importlib.reload(sys.modules['foo'])
from foo import bar
```

This is useful in a workflow like the following:

1. open python terminal
2. you load `bar` (i.e. `from foo import bar`)
3. you realize you need to make changes to `bar`
4. you make changes to `bar`
5. you want to use the new `bar` (i.e. you want to reload `bar`) without closing the existing python terminal